# A Question about mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, probability-limit-theorems

Consider a diffrentiable function on an interval $[a,b]$ where $f(a)=f(a+h)=0$ then by mean value theorem $f'(c)=0$ where $a<c<a+h$

let $$\lim \limits_{h\to 0}{h=0}$$

then by sandwitch theorem $c=a$

so that $f'(a)=0$

This is absurd I must have done a mistake somewhere.By the way I found the idea from the slope of the graph of $sin\frac{1}{x}$ near $0$

Comment: You can only let $h \to 0$ if $f(a+h) = 0$ for $h$ values arbitrarily close to $0$. The premise as written gives you only _one_ $h$ with $f(a+h) = 0$.

Comment: What is the context of this question? Are you trying to understand the mean value theorem or is this something else?

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer that's what I mean but still I don't see 'the mistake"

Comment: @tsktsktsk No, I am trying to find the flaw(which necessarily exists) in the above solution....

Comment: This idea does not seem to work with $\sin\frac1x,$ as it is not defined at $a=0$. Can you be more precise about what you're trying to do?

Comment: You're assuming $f(a) = f(a + h)$.  And sure enough if this holds for all small enough values of $h$ then $f'(a) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not absurd. *If* $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in $a$, and *if* there is a sequence $(h_n)$ in $(0, b-a)$ with $h_n \to 0$ and $f(a+h_n) = f(a)$ for all $n$, then indeed you have $f'(a) = 0$. You don't need the mean value theorem or any squeezing for that, it follows directly from the definition.

But you *need* the differentiability of $f$ in $a$, of course.

Your argument with the mean value theorem shows that if $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then the existence of a sequence $(h_n)$ as above implies that there are $c_n\in (a,b)$ with $c_n \to a$ and $f'(c_n) = 0$. From that last piece alone, you can only infer $f'(a) = 0$ if the derivative is continuous in $a$.

For the example you got the idea from, $\sin \frac1x$, you have the problem that you cannot extend that function to $0$ so that it even is continuous in $0$, let alone differentiable. If you squeeze down the amplitude of the oscillation near $0$ so that you get a differentiable function, for example $f(x) = x^2\sin\frac1x$ (and $f(0) = 0$, of course), then you have $f'(0) = 0$, but for this example, the derivative $f'$ is not continuous in $0$, so the squeezing argument cannot show that $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: @ daniel Fischer,just say that $f'(a)$ is non zero,what then?

Comment: I don't understand. Whether $f'(a)$ exists, and what value it has if it exists, depends on the values of $f$. If $f'(a)$ exists and is non-zero, the situation that you have a sequence $h_n\neq 0$ with $h_n\to 0$ and $f(a+h_n) = f(a)$ cannot arise.

Comment: Very clear and informative answer by Daniel (+1)!

Answer (score 0):

The sandwitch theorem **doesn't say** that $c=a\;$. $\;$This is your mistake !